# Can typed members of a data class be used to serialize/deserialize without custom a encoder/decoder?

Tags: python

Given a data class like:

```
@dataclass
class Customer
  name: str
  join_date: datetime
```

there are numerous cases where one might want to serialize this (to json or other), with the expectation that it be deserializable by another service. But currently, things like `json.dumps` won't handle this well, because it by default doesn't know how to handle `datetime`. The normal solution is to provide a custom encoder/decoder that will serialize `datetime` objects to `isostring`, and then for the decoder deserialize anything parsable using `datetime.fromisostring()` into a `datetime`. Which is great, but completely ignores all the type information available; when I deserialize a blob of text, I already *know* which fields are supposed to be `datetimes` - not because they look like a `datetime`, but because that's what my object defines the member as.

Also, consider some strange user provides their name as '2020-01-01' - what happens? With the commonly suggested course of parsing things that look like a `datetime` into a `datetime`, it will turn our string into the wrong sort of object for our class.

Is there not a way to do this more 'correctly', using the type annotations already provided to improve serialization logic?

Comment: You'd want to deserialise based on an expected *schema*, the dataclass in this case being that schema definition. So your deserialisation function would look like `deserialize(json_data, Customer)`. It can [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields) the class to see what fields are supposed to be what type and parse them accordingly.

Comment: The text of your question suggests you need to serialise specifically to json, is that correct? Or are you looking serialise and deserialise to any format that works?

Comment: @deceze I would expect this is something commonly available, as it's a pretty obvious strategy for serialization - I was looking to use something (somewhat) standard vs reinventing the wheel

Comment: @Grismar Nope; most any sort of serialization target is fine. Json is just ubiquitous in most orgs, so the most likely candidate to support this behavior.

Comment: AFAIK, Python doesn't have anything like this built in, but I'd be surprised if there wasn't some library doing exactly that. I've written some primitive, limited version of that kind of code, but it's not something worth sharing.

Comment: Have you looked into `pickle` (standard library) at all? Because it's intended exactly for this purpose and standard types work without problem with it.